# Cassandra cluster moving from unencrypted to encrypted state

Tags: encryption, cassandra

Does anyone have any experience of transferring a Cassandra cluster (Apache one, not a Datastax) from a non-encrypted state to an encrypted one?

By the "encrypted state" I refer to the enabling of server_encryption_options, client_encryption_options, and transparent_data_encryption_options.

The question is caused by the fact that while there is a feeling that it is impossible to transfer the communication between the nodes of Cassandra to a secure way without building a whole new cluster.

When I do enable server_encryption_options for racks only, new encrypted nodes can't find old unencrypted, even though they are in another DCs.

This leads me to the understanding, that Cassandra can't be flexible in node-to-node connections, they are either all encrypted, or all unencrypted.

I will also be glad if you can advise me where else I can ask this question: like community chats or something.

Cassandra version 3.11.2

This is nodetool status out (I tried to get three encrypted RAC_mycluster3 back into cluster):

```
Datacenter: DC_mycluster1
====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Rack
UN  10.62.167.101  60.98 MiB  256          100.0%           RAC_mycluster1
Datacenter: DC_mycluster2
====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Rack
UN  10.62.16.123  66.13 MiB  256          100.0%            RAC_mycluster2
Datacenter: DC_mycluster3
====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Rack
UN  10.62.2.3   66.09 MiB  256          100.0%              RAC_mycluster3
UN  10.62.2.4   66.11 MiB  256          100.0%              RAC_mycluster3
UN  10.62.2.5   66.18 MiB  256          100.0%              RAC_mycluster3
Datacenter: DC_mycluster4
====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)   Rack
UN  10.62.167.2  57.45 MiB  256          100.0%              RAC_mycluster4
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have experienced, Cassandra does not support transition of server-to-server encryption (`server_encryption_options`) in 3.11.x, and only transition of the client-to-server encryption (`client_encryption_options`) is supported.

Server-to-server encryption transition without downtime is in the next major release of Cassandra (4.0).
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10404

So for now, you have to create a new cluster and migrate the date.

For real time communication, the Cassandra community have the room in Apache Software Fundation's Slack, and you can join through https://s.apache.org/slack-invite.
There is `#cassandra` room you can ask questions.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, @yukim!

I am sorry for the question, but how do I join https://s.apache.org/slack-invite
It seems like I should have an @apache.org email to join this slack. Since I am not an apache committer I don't have one.

Comment: I don't think you need apache.org email to join. Do you have other slack account? You can sign in from the top right link.